# Howto connect an ip cam on raspberry pi 3 with fixed ip-address?

Tags: camera, static-ip, hotspot

```
Raspbian Jessie
Built-in wifi
RPI as hotspot
Security : WPA2
```

Is it possible to simulate the process called when you press the WPS button on a wifi box ?

Answer (score 1):

If the client device has a display, a random PIN can be generated
for each WPS registration session. wpa_supplicant can do this with a
control interface request, e.g., by calling wpa_cli:

```
sudo wpa_cli wps_pin any
```

This will return the generated 8-digit PIN which will then need to be
entered at the client to complete WPS registration. At that point,
the client will be enrolled with credentials needed to connect to the
AP to access the network.

If the client device does not have a display that could show the
random PIN, a hardcoded PIN that is printed on a label can be
used. wpa_supplicant is notified this with a control interface
request, e.g., by calling wpa_cli:

```
sudo wpa_cli wps_pin any 12345670
```

More details in the WPS readme can be found here: https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/README-WPS

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ wpa_cli wps_pin any 123
>>>> Get this error message : Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (null)  error: No such file or directory

Comment: add sudo to the command, I've edited my example

Comment: You will also need to ensure that WPS is enabled in the config file /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf I'm not sure what the defaults are for Raspbian